# Unity Facebook error: Send the Advertiser Tracking Enabled flag

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, ironsource

I have Facebook SDK in my Unity project, my game is approved on AppStore and Facebook showed me an error that I am not sending the Advertiser Tracking Enabled Flag. I went through their documentation for Unity and implemented everything like it was in their docs and send an update to AppStore. The update was approved and I even waited for a week to make sure it's not delayed, but the error didn't disappear.
I tried tweaking the code from their docs to force the flag to be always true, no matter what, and made sure to also set the flag to true after the Facebook SDK is initialized. The update was approved, and the error on Facebook is still present.

All other events with Facebook are working fine.

Did anyone succeed in implement this? If yes, what did you do to fix it?

[image: Facebook shows this error]

I have code before initializing IronSource, and also I copied after Facebook initialization.
AudienceNetwork.AdSettings.SetAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(true);

Unity: 2021.3.8f1
Facebook: 14.1.0
IronSource: 7.2.4

Comment: _"The update was approved, and the error on Facebook is still present."_ - just because you pushed an updated version to the app store, does not necessarily mean all of your app users will instantly update ...

Comment: well this is obvious :)

Comment: So you can say with absolute certainty then, that absolutely no user is using the old version any more? Because if not, then of course Facebook still showing the error would be justified, no?

Comment: Is there even any indication to begin with, that Facebook sees this as a "current" error?

Comment: Facebook is showing an error stating that they have not received a single event with this flag, I would imagine that it should disappear after they receive at least 1 event with this flag set to either true or false.

Comment: I think it is “current” because they display a big banner with a red warning above my app on Facebook, and also I can't run my marketing campaigns that would use the information gathered from this flag. 

If the flag started working, I would be able to create the marketing campaigns